# visual studio python Python 2.7.18 instead of the new one ( 3.9.7)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-3.9

I have encountered such a problem, that at visual studio i get always Python 2.7.18 instead the one I have at the terminal at my Mac.

I took all the steps to install **Homebrew** (Here is the guide i followed --> https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-homebrew-on-macos ), but nothing worked out.

Please help!

Thanks in advance

Comment: You tagged both `visual-studio` and `visual-studio-code`. These are two very different IDEs from Microsoft. Please make sure which one you are using.

Comment: Try with `python3` command and see.

Comment: Use command "python3 --version". Did you install Python successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install Python using Homebrew on macOS use at the Terminal prompt.
`brew install python3`

On macOS, make sure the location of your VS Code installation is included in your PATH environment variable. See [these setup instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac#_launching-from-the-command-line) for more information.

You can also try selecting the Python interpreter manually. "CTRL+SHIFT+P" and choose "Python: select interpreter".

[image]